# Updated Magento 1.9.2 to 1.9.3 now I have SQLSTATE[42S22]: error

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, database, sql

I am trying to help a friend who is having issues with their website. 
They had someone update their magento theme and after which they are now receiving the current error.

It seems that the update may have overwritten a column in their magento DB. I have tried downloading a backup in cpanel and uploading that however that did not seem to help.

this is the current error when trying to log into admin.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly.product_type_id' in 'field list', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT MAX(DATE_FORMAT(period, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS `period`, SUM(qty_ordered) AS `qty_ordered`, `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`.`product_id`, MAX(product_name) AS `product_name`, MAX(product_price) AS `product_price`, `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`.`product_type_id` FROM `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly` WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `existed_products` WHERE (sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly.product_id = existed_products.entity_id))) AND (store_id IN(0)) GROUP BY `product_id` LIMIT 5) AS `t`




Trace:
#0 /home/jeancoco/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/jeancoco/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/jeancoco/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#4 /home/jeancoco/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#5 /home/jeancoco/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home/jeancoco/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(225): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 /home/jeancoco/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(225): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getSize()
#8 /home/jeancoco/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(211): Varien_Data_Collection->getLastPageNumber()
#9 /home/jeancoco/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(522): Varien_Data_Collection->getCurPage()
#10 /home/jeancoco/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(569): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_renderLimit()
#11 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Report/Collection/Abstract.php(285): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load(false, false)
#12 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(550): Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Report_Collection_Abstract->load()
#13 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Tab/Products/Ordered.php(66): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#14 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(643): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Tab_Products_Ordered->_prepareCollection()
#15 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(649): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#16 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(922): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#17 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Grids.php(64): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Grids->_prepareLayout()
#19 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#20 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard.php(75): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...')
#21 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard->_prepareLayout()
#22 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#23 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#24 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#25 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#26 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#27 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#28 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#29 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#30 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(40): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#31 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#32 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#33 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#34 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#35 /home/jeancoco/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#36 /home/jeancoco/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#37 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the contents of `var/cache/`

Don't forget to `turn off Compiler, all Indexes, and all Caches` prior to performing an update.

This is  happened because the configuration cache is still active, and prevents Magento from detecting necessary database changes.

If Redis enabled, check your `app/etc/local.xml` file.

To flush Redis cache:

```
redis-cli flushall
```

Note:

> Check this table (f4p_sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly) have
>   'product_type_id' columns in it. If 'product_type_id' column is in
>   table then re-index and refresh cache. If 'product_type_id' column is
>   not in table then you need to create (upload backup table) table
>   again.

Comment: Yep, After deleting items from car/cache/ everything worked. thankyou so much.